# Track listing for "Britain Rocks" CD

Tags: album

I have a CD of British rock music from 15–20 years ago, which was given out as a free promo for British tourism.

[image]

The groups and titles aren't identified, but the cover says:

> For artist info and track listing go to: visit**Britain**rocks.ca/music

That URL has long since been hijacked for other purposes, and the usual ripping programs simply report it as "Unknown".

If anyone has a track listing, please let me know what it is.

Comment: Have you tried to https://www.shazam.com the various tracks?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the tracklist of the compilation you mention, but following [@Elements in Space answer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/12535/138) I've made a research on [Discogs](https://www.discogs.com/), the self-defined "largest online music database", for all the bands/artists on the album cover.

Here are the results. Maybe, following the link, you will be able to find some of the songs composing your British rock compilation.

- Emma Rugg: UK acoustic rock artist with a [2003 promo album](https://www.discogs.com/release/7857239-Emma-Rugg-Isolated-Impression)
- GK & the Renegades: no result on Discogs
- High Child: no result on Discogs
- Logan: [too many artists](https://www.discogs.com/search/?q=Logan&type=artist&strict=true) with this name
- Parade: [too many artists](https://www.discogs.com/search/?q=Parade&type=artist&strict=true) with this name
- Rase: UK band with a [2006 promo album](https://www.discogs.com/release/12492292-Rase-Rase)
- Rebel Yell: [none of the results](https://www.discogs.com/search/?q=rebel%20yell&type=artist&strict=true) seems to match criteria to be included in CD you mentioned
- Rubylux: UK band with an [album out in 2010](https://www.discogs.com/master/1408765-Rubylux-Fake-Control) (possibly they release some demos before that year)
- The Amateurs: [UK band](https://www.discogs.com/artist/7621404-The-Amateurs-3) with some songs appearing in 2005/2006 compilation
- The Brays: two different UK bands, one with a [single out in 2007](https://www.discogs.com/release/6038825-The-Brays-Let-It-Go) and one with a [single out in 2004](https://www.discogs.com/release/16585803-The-Brays-Illusions-Sound)
- The Capital: [none of the results](https://www.discogs.com/search/?q=The%20Capital&type=artist&strict=true) seems to match criteria to be included in CD you mentioned
- The Gadsens: no result on Discogs
- The More Assured: UK indie rock band with [songs released in 2007](https://www.discogs.com/master/1665915-The-More-Assured-All-In-Your-Head)
- Edian: no result on Discogs
- Tori Beaumont: [none of the results](https://www.discogs.com/artist/2870120-Tori-Beaumont) seems to match criteria to be included in CD you mentioned
- Voodoo Johnson: UK hard rock band with [a promo out in 2008](https://www.discogs.com/release/13767137-Voodoo-Johnson-Free-Audio-Flyer)

Answer (score 1):

It's not heaps easy to read, but on the left hand side of the album cover (the image you have posted), there is some writing that apparently lists the 16 artists (possibly out of order):

- Emma Rugg
- GK & the Renegades
- High Child
- Logan
- Parade
- Rase
- Rebel Yell
- Rubylux
- The Amateurs
- The Brays
- The Capital
- The Gadsens
- The More Assured
- Edian
- Tori Beaumont
- Voodoo Johnson

---

(As suggested in the comments)
The free service [Shazam](https://www.shazam.com/gb), can be used to identify music recordings by "listening" to music through your microphone.  It's remarkable quick and accurate at identifying many tracks.

While there is a tremendously large database, sometimes no match will be found, and sometimes a track will be misidentified, but this is quite rare.
However the title of this album suggests that these are all "unreleased" artists (at least at the time), so Shazam probably won't be able to identify all of them.

Comment: Nothing on the WaybackMachine either.